# Button Text does not Update

Tags: python, kivy

**>> BACKGROUND :**

I want to update/change the text of a Button in the SecondScreen with a press of a Button in the MainScreen. Well I did some research and did what I want, and when I checked in the terminal the text did change. BUUT, the text shown on the SecondScreen did not.

**>> THIS IS WHAT I DID :**

((Mind you that I'm only using snippets of code for example, I'm going to post the whole code below.))

```
Button:
    text:"PRESS TO CHANGE TEXT"
    on_press:
        root.funcself() 
        ## on press it goes to it's root and do the "funcself" function in it
```

which is :

```
class MainScreen(Screen):
    def funcself(self):
        app.second.funcscreen()
        ## it re-directs to the SecondScreen and do the "funcscreen" function
```

which is :

```
class SecondScreen(Screen):
    def funcscreen(self):
        self.ids["button"].text = "SUPPOSED TO CHANGE TO THIS"
```

and then I checked if I did it successfully by doing `print(self.ids["button"].text)`, and yes! 
It did change, but when I navigated to the next screen, the text shown still didn't change.

Anyone mind helping and explaining?

**FULL CODE :**

- python file :

  ```
  import kivy
  from kivy.app import App
  from kivy.lang import Builder
  from kivy.uix.label import Label
  from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
  from kivy.uix.button import Button
  from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
  from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen

  class MainScreen(Screen):
      def funcself(self):
          app.second.funcscreen()

  class SecondScreen(Screen):
      def funcscreen(self):
          value = self.ids["button"]
          self.ids["button"].text = "SUPPOSED TO CHANGE TO THIS"

  kv = Builder.load_file("reproduce.kv")
  class reproduce(App):
      second = SecondScreen()
      def build(self):
          return kv

      def change_screen(self, x):
          scrnmngr = self.root.ids["sm"]
          scrnmngr.current = x

      def check(self):
          print(self.second.ids["button"].text)

  if __name__ == "__main__":
      app = reproduce()
      app.run()
  ```
- kivy file :

  ```
  <MainScreen>:
      GridLayout:
          rows:2
          Label:
              text: "PRESS TO GO TO THE NEXT PAGE"
          GridLayout:
              cols:2
              Button:
                  text:"PRESS TO CHANGE TEXT"
                  on_press:
                      root.funcself()

              Button:
                  text:">>>"
                  on_press:
                      app.change_screen("second")
                      root.manager.transition.direction = "left"

  <SecondScreen>:
      GridLayout:
          rows:2
          Label:
              id:label
              text: "PRESS TO CHECK AND RETURN TO PREV PAGE"
          Button:
              id:button
              text:"TEXT BEFORE CHANGE"
              on_press:
                  app.change_screen("first")
                  root.manager.transition.direction = "right"
                  app.check()
  GridLayout:
      cols: 1
      ScreenManager:
          id:sm
          MainScreen:
              id:main
              name:"first"
          SecondScreen:
              id:second 
              name:"second"
  ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Root Cause

It did not change because there are two instances of `SecondScreen()` i.e. one instantiated in the kv file and the other one instantiated in the App class, `reproduce()`. The view presented is created from the kv file and the second instance does not has a view associated to it.

## Solution

There are two solutions to the problem, and remove `second = SecondScreen()` from the App class.

### [Kivy Screen » default property manager](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.screenmanager.html#basic-usage)

> Each screen has by default a property manager that gives you the
>   instance of the [ScreenManager](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.screenmanager.html) used.

### Using get_screen()

```
class MainScreen(Screen):
    def funcself(self):
        self.manager.get_screen('second').funcscreen()
```

### Using App.get_running_app() & ids

```
class MainScreen(Screen):
    def funcself(self):
        App.get_running_app().root.ids.second.funcscreen()
```

## Example

In the following example, there are two solutions provided but one of it is commented off.

### main.py

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen


class MainScreen(Screen):
    def funcself(self):
        self.manager.get_screen('second').funcscreen()
        # App.get_running_app().root.ids.second.funcscreen()


class SecondScreen(Screen):
    def funcscreen(self):
        value = self.ids["button"]
        self.ids["button"].text = "SUPPOSED TO CHANGE TO THIS"


kv = Builder.load_file("reproduce.kv")


class reproduce(App):

    def build(self):
        return kv

    def change_screen(self, x):
        scrnmngr = self.root.ids["sm"]
        scrnmngr.current = x

    def check(self):
        print(self.second.ids["button"].text)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    reproduce().run()
```

## Output

[image: Result]

Comment: thanks for answering my question! especially with providing this detailed answer! im very grateful for every help i can get.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. You are most welcome. [If you want to say "thank you", vote on or accept that person's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

[If you accept someone else's answer: You gain +2 reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)

Answer (score 0):

The `second` attribute you define in your app class, is a new instantiation of the screen, and not really the instance you got in your screenmanager, which you add in kv. This is why when you check, you see its changed, but not on the right instance. And again when you call app.second.func, from mainscreen, again its the wrong instance.

But your app always has a root. In your case its the gridlayout. And every screen has a manager. There are a couple of ways to acces it. But you can do like this.

In your mainscreen class in kv:

```
Button:
    text:"PRESS TO CHANGE TEXT"
    on_press:
        root.manager.get_screen("second").ids["button"].text = "Something"
```

Here it gets the screenmanager, and uses its `get_screen()` method to get the screen named second, and then the id's of that kv rule.

Comment: oh that makes alot of sense! I thank you very muchh for answering my question, appreciate it man.

Comment: @flyynn no problem :)